How to delete parent SSR div in `use client` button?
I have this NextJS(v15) component redered with SSR and want the Item to be available for search engines. And I have a delete button that should delete this component from DOM. I can delete the parent in DeleteMeButton with getElementById(parentId) or by passing the parent ref to the DeleteMeButton. But what is the best React way to do this using SSR + use client? Thanks.
export const Item = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DeleteMeButton />
      Content here
    </div>
  );
};


Delete.tsx
("use client");
export const DeleteMeButton = () => {
  const handleDelete = () => {
    //delete the parent component here
  };
  return <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete me</button>;
};


What about using state? You can then pass the delete button a callback which updates the state. With the updated state you can optionally render the item

@evolutionxbox As I understand it, you cannot use state in SSRs (server components) as it will become a client component

If you would like the item to disappear on the server too, then you will need to render using data from a database of some kind.

@evolutionxbox thanks, that is the another variant but I don't want to refetch the data from server. Just remove the item from the list in a React way

It sounds like you'll need Item to become a client component.

@evolutionxbox nah... then I would go for getElementById(parentId).remove()

That's probably not a good way to go. You're making changes outside of react and will likely cause issues

Generally speaking it's not a good idea to manipulate the DOM managed by React yourself. It defeats the purpose entirely of using React.
There seems to be a misinterpretation about how client components work. Client components are still prerendered on the server, the only thing that does not execute are hooks that depend on effects (such as useState).
This means that you can safely use 'use client' in your Item.tsx component file while still keeping its content available to search engines if its initial or default state contains this information.
Let's visit the solution you could implement:
Item.tsx:
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Item = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const handleDelete = () => setShow(false);

  if (!show) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <DeleteMeButton onClick={handleDelete} />
      Content here
    </div>
  );
}

Delete.tsx:
interface Props {
  onClick: () => void;
}

export const DeleteMeButton = ({ onClick }: Props) => {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Delete me</button>;
};

This will still prerender the div with Content here to be available in search engines because show is initialized to true.
